# Move home folder back on to SSD

Tags: 13.04, hard-drive, home-directory, ssd

My current setup at the moment is I have my system partition on my SSD, and my home folder on a 320GB HDD. The HDD is unfortunately beginning to die with a couple bad sectors coming up, so I'd like to move my home folder on to my SSD. What is the best approach for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do it from a LiveCD. Home directories are constantly being written to so there's no really nice clean way to deal with this (short of going to TTY1 and `telinit 3` - it's possible but it isn't friendly).

- Copy the data over
- Remove any relevant bind-mounts you have in `/etc/fstab` (the version on your SSD, not the LiveCD's version).
- Reboot.